# Write and read txt file

Tags: java

I'm trying to do project which contains patient information and print them if user want. But it is currently adding only one person. I want to add infinite information and I don't how can I fix it.

```
public static void saveChanges(ArrayList<Human> humans) throws IOException {
    File veritabani = new File("patients.txt");
    System.gc();
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(veritabani, "rw");
    raf.close();
    veritabani.delete();
    int ctrWhile = 0;
    for (int yazdir = 0; yazdir < humans.size(); yazdir++) {

        File f = new File("patients.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
        String tName=humans.get(yazdir).getNameAndSurname();
        int tID=humans.get(yazdir).getTC();
        int tAge=humans.get(yazdir).getAge();
        boolean tInsuance=humans.get(yazdir).isInsurance();
        String tComplain=humans.get(yazdir).getComplain();

        if (ctrWhile== 0) {
            pw.append(tName+"-"+tID+"-"+tAge+"-"+"-"+tInsuance+"-"+tComplain+"-");
            ctrWhile++;
        } else {
            pw.append("\n"+tName+"-"+tID+"-"+tAge+"-"+"-"+tInsuance+"-"+tComplain+"-");

        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `RandomAccessFile` is pointless here. `new FileOutputStream(...)` will create it if necessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each time through your loop, you appear to create a new file, write to it, and close it. Therefore each time through your loop you will overwrite the file created before.

Create the file before entering the loop, and close it after you've completed the loop; only write to it within the loop.

Comment: It work but still i cant print all information in patients.txt it's only print one patient

Comment: They're passing `true` as the `append` parameter of the `FileOutputStream` constructor.  I don't think this is the actual problem.  I suspect the actual problem is that there's actually only one item in `humans`.

Comment: I think @RyanMentley is correct, I missed that you were appending to that file.

Comment: Yeah when i try again informatins gone and i dont know why human have only one item.

Comment: Well, to get help with that, we're going to have to see how the information gets in there...

Comment: I deleted to 'veritabani.delete();' and 'ctrWhile++;' it's work now i can freely print and wrote information.